# Passar valor para array - angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

Eu tenho este `formGroup`:

```
 this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [null],
  code: [null, Validators.required],
  description: [null],
  percent: [null, Validators.required],
  dueDate: [null, Validators.required],
  dataCreate: [null],
  couponPlan: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});
```

}

e preciso passar os valores para couponPlan, inicialmente, é apenas `planId`, que preciso passar.
No `submit` do formulário, eu estou tentando algo como:

```
this.formGroup.value['couponPlan'] =  this.formBuilder.group([this.plansids]);
```

Porém não funciona, ele não cria o array do couponPlan.
Já tentei de várias maneira `this.formGroup.controls['couponPlan'] =  this.formBuilder.group([this.plansids]);`

Ele fica errado os valores de planIds. Preciso preencher correto, para receber estes valores da lista na minha API. Olha como está ficando os planId.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No formArray é necessário incluir uma lista de abstractControls, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    telefones: this.formBuilder.array([])
});

const telefones = ['(00) 0000 - 0000', '(11) 1111 - 1111'];
telefones.forEach(tel => (this.form.controls['telefones'] as FormArray).push(new FormControl(tel)));
```

Caso precise de um array de objetos pode se usar um formGroup ao invés de formControl.

Comment: Obrigado!! Consegui chegar na solução, com ajuda do seu comentário.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.formGroup.value['couponPlan'] =  this.formBuilder.array(this.plansids.map(plan=> new FormControl(plan)); // ou plan.propriedade
```

Comment: Não deu certo, ficou da mesma forma que na pergunta.

Comment: Estou tentando algo como  `for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const billInstallment = {}; 
        billInstallment['planId'] = new FormControl(this.selection.selected.map(x=> x.id));
        form.push(new FormGroup(billInstallment));
      }`  mas ainda não deu certo.